# error in my Times Table app in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I get the following error when I run my app:

[image: Code error]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50   
    }

    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = String((Int(slider.value * 20)) * (indexPath.row + 1))
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: do you user interface builder?

Comment: what is `slider`? Does it have a value always?

Comment: Make sure that `slider` was successfully hooked up in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be creating a new cell in each call to `cellForRowAt`. You should be using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to try to recycle a cell. That's not the cause of your problem, but it's important nevertheless.

It's hard to be sure why you are crashing. Can you post the declaration of `slider`? My guess is that it's an implicitly unwrapped optional (declared with an `!`)

Does the declaration look something like this:

```
@IBoutlet var slider: UISlider!
```

If so, set a breakpoint at the line that's crashing and check to see if slider is nil. (Although you usually get a different error about attempting to unwrap a nil optional when that's the cause.)

Comment: Thank you so much! It turns out some how my IBOutlet and IBActions somehow got disconnected. Thanks for the help!